# The vectors b that are not in the column space C(A) form a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

True or false (with a counterexample if false):
The vectors b that are not in the column space C(A) form a subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Any subspace contains the zero vector.

Comment: Yes, I know. And then?

Comment: $0 \in C(A)$ since $C(A)$ is subspace so $0$ can't be an element of $C(A)^c$